# Clip path is not working for Firefox, IE, or Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using a carousel for displaying images with some content. For showing the image I am using clip path. It shows perfectly in Chrome, but it does not work in IE, Edge, or Firefox.

```css
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail a>img,
.thumbnail>img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  background-image: url('../../Images/Plain-BG.PNG');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: Kamban !important;
}

footer {
  background-image: url(../../Images/DT-Logo.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.news-img {
  width: 42.5%;
  margin-top: 13%;
  clip-path: polygon(6% 4%, 94% 11%, 94% 91%, 5% 92%);
  margin-left: 8.5%;
}

.title {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  height: auto;
  left: 57%;
  color: #fff;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>a>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail a>img,
.thumbnail>img {
  height: auto !important;
}

.title p {
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-word;
}

header {
  background-image: url(../../Images/Mukkiya-Seithigal.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  right: 4%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Maindiv">
  <header></header>
  <article>
    <div id='carousel-container'>
      <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="wholediv carousel-inner">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

I am getting the image URL and its content from my feed URL via a script. So I am binding details through the script only.

Comment: IE and edge do not support clip-path

Comment: how can I overcome this??

Comment: There is a polyfill but I have not personally used it so I can't advice https://github.com/AlfonsoFilho/ClipPath

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using SVG with your image as a pattern and your `clip-path` as `points`.

```html
<svg height="186px" width="300px">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" height="100%" width="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
      <image height="1" width="1" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Crossing_the_River_Styx.jpg/300px-Crossing_the_River_Styx.jpg"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="18 7, 282 20, 282 150, 15 171" fill="url(#pattern)"></polygon>
</svg>
```

It is possible also to use some script to "convert" a dynamically loaded image into SVG. For example:

```js
function clip() {
  let img = document.querySelector('img');

  let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  svg.setAttribute('height', img.clientHeight + 'px');
  svg.setAttribute('width', img.clientWidth + 'px');
  svg.querySelector('pattern image').setAttribute('xlink:href', img.src);

  let pointsRaw = img.getAttribute('data-points').split(/,\s/);
  let points = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < pointsRaw.length; i++) {
    let coord = pointsRaw[i].replace(/%/g, '').split(' ');
    let x = img.clientWidth * coord[0] / 100;
    let y = img.clientHeight * coord[1] / 100;
    points += Math.round(x) + ' ' + Math.round(y) + ' ';
  }
  svg.querySelector('polygon').setAttribute('points', points);

  img.style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('button').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Crossing_the_River_Styx.jpg/300px-Crossing_the_River_Styx.jpg" data-points="6% 4%, 94% 11%, 94% 80%, 5% 92%">

<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" height="100%" width="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
      <image height="1" width="1" xlink:href="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon fill="url(#pattern)"></polygon>
</svg>

<button onclick="clip()">Clip</button>
```

Comment: Can we use this method with <path> instead of <polygon> ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently clip-path does not have full browser-support. More info at: 
https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

[image]

As it shows in the notes, SVG is supported... if using embedded or object elements. See:
 https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg